# Does a countable integral domain have only finitely many maximal ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, examples-counterexamples

Does a countable integral domain have only finitely many maximal ideals?

I've been thinking about this for awhile, I'd really appreciate a proof or counter example!! Thanks!

Comment: I think the integers are a counter-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not necessarily. A counterexample is $\mathbf Z$: its maximal ideals are generated by the primes  and, as as you know, there's an infinity of them.